# How to export variable in TypeScript and fill it?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have `response.ts` file with variable declaration:

```
export declare var passportInfoResponse: IGetPassportInfoResponse;
```

In another file I import this:

```
import  {passportInfoResponse} from '../../models/responses/response';
```

How to fill this variable? I tried:

```
passportInfoResponse = data;
```

This variable should be a global.

Comment: If it's global, why do you need to import it?

Comment: I use it in Angular 5, so I want to store data in one file and get access to this model everywhere

Comment: If you're using Angular it seems like this could work with a provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimal solution is to use angular service to provide this value / change it. But this is in Angular case.

If you still want to go your way / common case you cannot assign to imported token. What you can do is create a setter function that changes the value:

```
interface IGetPassportInfoResponse {}

export declare var passportInfoResponse: IGetPassportInfoResponse;

export function setPassportInfoResponse(val: IGetPassportInfoResponse) {
  passportInfoResponse = val;
}
```

and set the value with the imported function instead of assignment

```
import  {passportInfoResponse, setPassportInfoResponse} from '../../models/responses/response';

console.log(passportInfoResponse);

const data = {};

setPassportInfoResponse(data);

console.log(passportInfoResponse);
```

Actually Angular seems to be using this approach with [enableProdMode](https://angular.io/api/core/enableProdMode) function.

Comment: I see error compile  message:  `passportInfoResponse` is not variable

Comment: forgot word `function`; updated the answer; still cannot get your error

Comment: Whats is `setPassportInfoResponse`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, may be to use set/get instead?

Comment: if you can make it working, why not, however I'm not sure it is possible